# How I can get one value from JSON file for use it in component code, Angular 2 (8.2.8)?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

My JSON file is:

```html
{
  "pagesList":
  [
      {
        "pageUrl": "index",
        "imgUrl": "glavnaya",
        "imgNumber": 17
      },
      {
        "pageUrl": "second",
        "imgUrl": "secondimg",
        "imgNumber": 10
      }      
  ]
}
```

For next actions I need to get value 17 (from "imgNumber": 17) as a variable in the component code. But I don't need to use this variable in template, only in component code. Getting data from json file with `img-carusel.service.ts`:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImgCaruselService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPagesJson() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/from-server/pages.json');
  }

}
```

After that in component `testzone.component.ts` I'm transforming json to array of objects:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImgCaruselService } from '../img-carusel.service';
import {Pages} from '../pages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testzone',
  templateUrl: './testzone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testzone.component.css'],
  providers: [ImgCaruselService]  
})
export class TestzoneComponent implements OnInit {

  pageParams:Pages [] = [];

  constructor(private imgcaruselService: ImgCaruselService) {   
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.imgcaruselService.getPagesJson().subscribe(data => this.pageParams=data["pagesList"]);    
  }
  
  //imgnum=this.pageParams[0]["imgNumber"];
}
```

And using class `Pages` for it:

```html
export class Pages {
    pageUrl: string;
    imgUrl:string;
    imgNumber: number;
}
```

And showing it on screen throuth the template `testzone.component.html` :

```html
pageParams = {{pageParams|json}}

pageParams[0].imgUrl = {{pageParams[0]?.imgUrl}}

<ul *ngFor="let item of pageParams">
  <li>imgUrl = {{item?.imgUrl}}</li>
  <li>pageUrl = {{item?.pageUrl}}</li>
  <li>imgNumber = {{item?.imgNumber}}</li>
</ul>
```

As result I'v got:

```html
pageParam = [ { "pageUrl": "index", "imgUrl": "glavnaya", "imgNumber": 17 }, { "pageUrl": "second", "imgUrl": "secondimg", "imgNumber": 10 } ]
pageParam2 = glavnaya

    imgUrl = glavnaya
    pageUrl = index
    imgNumber = 17

    imgUrl = second
    pageUrl = secondimg
    imgNumber = 10
```

So in template I can output all values from json file, its allright. After that I'm trying to assign value 17 (from "imgNumber": 17) by new variable in component code: `imgnum=this.pageParams[0]["imgNumber"];` with hope to subsequent using it. And after browser refreshes I haved a clean screen without something. No messages about errors in IDE, only clean screen.

How I can get access to separate data by using it in component code not for output in temlate? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i would recommend using the http.get overload of httpclient method.

so instead of

```
 return this.http.get('/assets/from-server/pages.json');
```

use

```
  return this.http.get<Pages[]>('/assets/from-server/pages.json');
```

Otherwise

Instead of

```
this.imgcaruselService.getPagesJson().subscribe(data => this.pageParams=data["pagesList"]);
```

use

```
this.imgcaruselService.getPagesJson().subscribe(data => this.pageParams= JSON.parse(data["pagesList"]));
```